# Java - System.setOut does not save an exception message

Tags: java, exception, stdout

It seems that `System.setOut()` does not work in this test case.

Here are problem description.

1. `test0` executes `System.setOut(new PrintStream(byteBuffer))` so that it stores standard output.
2. `test0` invokes `AddChild1_wy_v1.main`.
3. In the `AddChild1_wy_v1.main`, `xml.addChild(null)` generates an exception message.
4. The exception message should be stored in `byteBuffer`, but it seems it wasn't.. JVM stops running the test case once the exception message pops up. And the remaining code after `AddChild1_wy_v1.main` are not executed.

Is there a way for jvm to execute the remaining code in `test0`?

`NanoAddChild1_wy_v1Tests.java`

```
package tests;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import net.n3.nanoxml.*;

public class NanoAddChild1_wy_v1Tests extends TestCase {

    public void test0() throws Exception {      //addchild1.out
        String result;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer;

        byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(byteBuffer));
        AddChild1_wy_v1.main(new String[] {"/home/junghyun/Dev/nanoxml/inputs/simple.xml"});
        result = new String(byteBuffer.toByteArray());
        assertEquals(result, "Exception in thread \"main\" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: child must not be null\n\tat net.n3.nanoxml.XMLElement.addChild(XMLElement.java:165)\n\tat AddChild1_wy_v1.main(AddChild1_wy_v1.java:47)\n");
    }
}
```

`AddChild1_wy_v1.java`

```
package tests;

import net.n3.nanoxml.IXMLParser;
import net.n3.nanoxml.IXMLReader;
import net.n3.nanoxml.StdXMLReader;
import net.n3.nanoxml.XMLElement;
import net.n3.nanoxml.XMLParserFactory;
import net.n3.nanoxml.XMLWriter;

public class AddChild1_wy_v1
{

    public static void main(String args[])
        throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java DumpXML file.xml");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);
        }

        IXMLParser parser = XMLParserFactory.createDefaultXMLParser();
        IXMLReader reader = StdXMLReader.fileReader(args[0]);
        parser.setReader(reader);
        XMLElement xml = (XMLElement) parser.parse();

    xml.addChild (null);
    (new XMLWriter(System.out)).write(xml); 
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: please post code as text so one can copy&paste it to the answer. An image is not so good.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm done edited.

Comment: great! I used your code in my answer now. I also edited your question in the way it is expected here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you never write that Exception at all.

You just throw it upwards. Try catch it and have ex.printStackTrace();

Also that will go to standard error, unless you specifically say otherwise.

As by your request I will leave the `test0` method unaltered, you can use it the way it is.

in `AddChild1_wy_v1.java`:

```
public class AddChild1_wy_v1    {
    public static void main(String args[]) // note that I don't throw the Exception.
    {
      try {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java DumpXML file.xml");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);
        }

        IXMLParser parser = XMLParserFactory.createDefaultXMLParser();
        IXMLReader reader = StdXMLReader.fileReader(args[0]);
        parser.setReader(reader);
        XMLElement xml = (XMLElement) parser.parse();

        xml.addChild (null);
        (new XMLWriter(System.out)).write(xml); 
      } catch (Exception any) {
        any.printStackTrace(System.out); // note that I send the Stack Trace to standard out here.
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, this test case is made by other people at 2005. I'd like to keep the codes unchanged. Do you think any old version jvm can run this test case without an error?

Comment: @Junghyun It has nothing to do with jvm. This code would act the same in all java versions since the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

There's 3 default streams:

```
System.in : InputStream
System.out :PrintStream
System.err :PrintStream
```

So to set each one there is 3 methods:

```
public static void setIn(InputStream in) {...}
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {...}
public static void setErr(PrintStream err) {...}
```

To set `System.err` you must use `System.setErr(yourStream);`

For another question: you just need to use

```
try {
    //throwing exception
} catch (Exception e) { 
    //act on exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your method call in a [`try-catch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) to continue past the exception:

```
try {
    AddChild1_wy_v1.main(...);
} catch(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
// the rest of your code will execute
```

Exceptions are printed to standard error, not standard output. Try [`System.setErr`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29).

Never post images of your code.

Comment: Could you answer the question that I wrote in Angelo's answer if you know anything about that? Thanks.